# What (and when) to expect from EE6 (and from updates of EE5)?

Tags: eeharbor

For example: since EE acquired by the Packet Tide, should we expect features of EEHarbor addons in EE core?

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: We know that member functions are having a major overhaul, a new UI, and customisable entry listings at least. I'm sure there will be a few other enhancements that we don't yet know about.

Comment: Nice! The member stuff is pretty outdated. That'll be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Check out these posts from the expressionengine blog

https://expressionengine.com/blog/expressionengine-february-update

https://expressionengine.com/blog/expressionengine-6-update